# Performance degrades adding reference type variables to a list in parallel loops

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have found adding a class variable to a list in parallel loops causes cpu to use only half of its resourses. This code loads my CPU 50%:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 100000000, i =>
        {
            var list = new List<MyClass>();

            for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
                list.Add(new MyClass() {Value = j});
        });

    }
}
```

This code loads my CPU almost 100%:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 100000000, i =>
        {
            var list = new List<int>();

            for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
                list.Add(j);
        });

    }
}
```

Is it possible to use 100% of my CPU adding class variables to a list in parallel loops?

**UPDATE:**
If the reason for such behavior is frequent run of GC then the following code would perform better.

```
class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 8, i =>
        {
            var list = new List<MyClass>();

            for (var j = 0; j < 100000000; j++)
                list.Add(new MyClass() {Value = j});
        });

    }
}
```

But the cpu usage is 20% only in this case

**UPDATE 2:**
Tested: enabling or disabling concurrent GC changes nothing in performance:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
      <gcConcurrent enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for this behavior is that you're creating lots of objects that become garbage quickly. This means the garbage collector has to run very often. And when the GC runs on one thread, it might need to pause other threads (“stop the world”), which will result in low CPU utilization.

The lesson you should learn from this is that you shouldn't measure nonsensical code like this, it will tell you very little about the performance of real code.

**EDIT:** Garbage collector doesn't run when there's memory to be deallocated (because there is no way it could know that), it runs when you're allocating memory. And when there is lots of allocated memory, the GC has to run longer to scan all that memory. So it makes sense that your third version uses even less CPU, since the GC is pausing the other threads for a longer time.

Comment: Good diagnosis. In my experience enabling concurrent GC helps tremendously in situations like this.

Comment: Thank you. May be I'll switch my code to structs after performance tests.